# Restore x64 NuGet packages via PowerShell

Tags: nuget, visual-studio-2022, cicd, .net-7.0

I've got .NET 7.2 WEB API project, which was build with x64 Visual Studio 2022 v17.2 - v17.4. Now I try to set up CI/CD pipeline, for what I use .yml with following code:

```
    - 'C:\nuget.exe restore server.csproj'
    - '& "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\MSBuild\Current\Bin\MSBuild" server.csproj'
```

Constantly getting error:

```
error NETSDK1064: Package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Analyzers, version 7.0.2 was not found. It might have been deleted since NuGet restore. Otherwise, NuGet restore might have only partially completed, which might have been due to maximum path length restrictions.
```

What I've tried is:

- I enabled Win32 long paths as it suggested [here](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/error-restoring-the-nuget-after-upgrading-solution-to-net-6)
- I've created new WeatherForecast project and new repo with name tst, so path certainly cannot be shorter

Nothing gives any success

As far as I understand, the problem is that I use **x32** NuGet CLI with **x64** VS 2022 builder. Bit depth does not match. As far as my project uses .NET 7, I cannot use VS 2019. Also I cannot find x64 NuGet CLI - [official site](https://www.nuget.org/downloads) provides only x32 versions

I need some way to restore packages and then build the project from YML file. What surprised me is that I can sequentially run all commands from .yml in cmd.exe and as a result I will get build with no errors. I tried to `$ whoami` prior to any of .yml command and it gives me that it's SYSTEM user, which by the way got full access to IIS's wwwroot folder, but the error triggers prior deployment step, so I have no clue how it could be related

I'm stuck, got no idea what to do, but guess that solution is quite simple, I'm to blurry now. SOers please help me

**Solution**

Great thanks to [@mu88](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4919526/mu88)!

In accordance to his suggestions yml took that form:

```
  - 'dotnet restore service.csproj -v n'
  - 'dotnet service.csproj'
```

And everything works as it supposed to

Comment: There is no .NET Framework 7 (old .NET stack) - do you mean .NET 7 (new stack)? Try to increase NuGet's verbosity when running `restore`

Comment: @mu88 you are correct, my mistake, fixed question

Comment: Did you increase the verbosity and can share some logs?

Comment: @mu88 yep, I set up it to Detailed level on local machine and on machine where build is going on, but log looks the same. Added it to question body

Comment: You're still executing `dotnet restore reporting-web-service.csproj` but not `dotnet restore reporting-web-service.csproj -v n`

Comment: Okay, `restore` looks okay. Can you try building your project with `dotnet build` instead of `msbuild`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some investigation (see the comment section) we found out that using `dotnet build` instead of `msbuild` solves the problem.